# Kann ein Mensch "nicht zu gebrauchen sein"?

Tags: word-usage

Ich habe neulich folgenden Satz gehört:

> Den Termin müssen wir auf den 20.11 legen, denn ich habe am 15.11 Geburtstag und am nächsten Tag **bin ich dann nicht zu gebrauchen.**

Nach OpenThesaurus ist der Ausdruck jedoch ein Synonym für baufällig, kaputt, entzwei usw. 
*War das also ein metaphorischer Ausdruck oder verwendet man ihn als Synonym für "mitgenommen" oder "erschlagen"?*

Comment: It means that the person who says about himself that he is "nicht zu gebrauchen" ("not useful") can't do his work for whatever reason. Work here includes the job he gets money from but also e.g. cleaning the house and such. Every kind of "productive" work you normaly do over the day. If he says he is "nicht zu gebrauchen" due to his birthday it means he most likely will have a party long into the night and maybe even drinks alot of alcohole.

Comment: You may find it intressting that "auflegen" for a Termin is formal/business language while "bin ich dann nicht zu gebrauchen." is more colloquial. The reason why there is such a change in wording could be various e.g. the person who says that sentence is unsure if the person he speaks with has understanding for things like that or maybe it's a conversation between people who know each other good while using formal language do to beeing in a work environment. You have to interpet it yourself with the further context you have, but maybe it's intressting to know for you.

Comment: Hier auflegen zu benutzen ist schlechtes Deutsch, besser ist : "Den Termin müssen wir auf den 20.11 legen".

Comment: @Uwe Und wie wäre es mit *verschieben*?

Comment: Ja, man kann einen Termin auch verschieben.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Äußerungen wie

> Am Abend nach der Arbeit bin ich zu nix mehr zu gebrauchen

sind umgangssprachlich durchaus verbreitet. Der Sprecher will sagen, dass er müde und zu weiteren - möglicherweise den Geist fordernden - Aktivitäten nicht mehr fähig ist.

Im Falle des Beispiels aus der Frage spielt der Sprecher auf seinen Zustand nach einer Geburtstagsfeier an. Man darf annehmen, dass er voraussieht, dem Alkohol rege zusprechen zu werden und darum am nächsten Tag nicht in gewohntem Maße leistungsfähig zu sein.

Im schriftlichen Verkehr verwendet man das kaum.

Ähnliche Ausdrücke aus der Umgangsspräche wären:

> Ich bin total groggy
>
> Da bin ich fertig.
>
> Da bin ich fix und foxy.
>
> Ich bin knülle.
>
> Nach der Arbeit bin ich total Matsch, da mach ich nix mehr, da flätz ich mich allenfalls auf dem Sofa rum und kuck fern.

OpenThesaurus scheint die Anwendung von "zu nichts zu gebrauchen" auf Menschen im Sinne von Müdigkeit/Erschöpftheit halt noch nicht mitbekommen zu haben.

Comment: Die Unterstellung des Alkohols braucht es in der Antwort nicht.

Comment: OpenThesaurus liegt da jetzt auch nicht so falsch. Ich würde den Ausspruch auch als metaphorische Verwendung von `kaputt` ansehen.

Comment: Der Ausdruck ist hier natürlich im übertragenen Sinne gebraucht. Denn es geht ja nicht um ein konkretes "Gebrauchen" der Person. Doch könnte man den Satz *Der ist zu nichts zu gebrauchen" sich in anderem Kontext auch im direkten Sinne verwendet vorstellen: Personalchef bespricht sich mit seinem Kollegen über die Verwendbarkeit verschiedener Bewerber: "Den da können wir gut brauchen... der da kommt vielleicht als Hausmeister in Frage... und den da... nein, der ist zu nichts zu gebrauchen."

Comment: Es gibt ja auch das schöne Prädikat "Zu allem fähig, aber zu nichts zu gebrauchen."